# object-oriented question

Tags: php

I am attempting to put all my database connections in 1 php file, rather than in each of my individual php pages. I have the following:

//conn.php:

```
<?php

class conn {
   var $username = "name";
   var $password = "password";
   var $server = "localhost";
   var $port = "3306";
   var $databasename = "db";
   var $tablename = "tablename";
   var $connection;

   public function getConnected() {

       $this->connection = mysqli_connect(
       $this->server,
       $this->username,
       $this->password,
       $this->databasename,
       $this->port
        );
}


}
?>
```

// file.php:

```
<?php
require_once("conn.php");

class myClass{

public function con() {

$conn = new conn();
$conn->getConnected();    
}

public function myF() {
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn->connection, "SELECT * FROM $conn->tablename");

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
}
?>
```

I then call this as follows:

$myNew = new myClass();
$myNew->con();
$myNew->myF();

When I call this, I get the following error:

Undefined property: myClass::$connection

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In `myClass`, you connect in `con()`, but `$conn` is a variable local to that method; i.e. the class itself does not have access to it. To fix this,

```
class myClass {

    public $conn;

    public function con() {
        $this->conn = new conn();
        $this->conn->getConnected();    
    }

    public function myF() {
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->conn->connection, "SELECT * FROM {$this->conn->tablename}");
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }

}
```

Comment: thx, but I get Undefined variable: conn in line 11...it doesn't like the $conn->tablename

Comment: @user522962 I should have fixed it—let me know if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

myF doesn't have access to $conn or connection

1.) declare connection public in Conn

```
class MyConn {
  private static $conn; //it should be static since it only exists once

  public __construct() {
    self::$conn = new Conn()->getConnected();
  }

  public myF() {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare(self::$conn->connection, "SELECT * FROM self::$conn->tablename");
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  }
}
```

Okay... As per your reasoning for doing this -> I would create an array of that information in a hash like:

```
class MyConn {
  private $connections = array(
    "blog" => array(
       "username" => "name",
       "password" => "password",
       "server" = "localhost",
       "port" => "3306",
       "databasename" => "db",
       "tablename" => "blog"
    ),
    "admin" => array(
       "username" => "name2",
       "password" => "password2",
       "server" = "localhost",
       "port" => "3306",
       "databasename" => "db",
       "tablename" => "admin"
    )
  );

  private static $active_connection;

  public __construct($connection_name = NULL) {
    if(in_array($connection_name, $this->connections)) {
      self::$active_connection = mysqli_connect($this->connections[$connection_name]);
    } else {
      throw new Exception("That is not a valid connection name!");
    }
  }

  public conn() {
    return self::$active_connection;
  }
}
```

now you can do:

```
$blog_conn = new MyConn('blog');
```

Comment: I'm just trying to be more organized. I have a bunch of different classes that each have my db connection variables defined w/in them. I'd like to have my db connection variables in a separate file, that's all

Comment: @Seth You need to call getConnected() on MyConn::conn.

Comment: I get "Parse error: parse error in line 10"...it doesn't like the line w/  self::conn = new Conn();

Comment: I messed it up the first time - its been fixed and I gave you a better solution to your problem (i forgot the $)

Comment: Your fixes still won't work: For #1, you'd be putting `null` in MyConn::conn, since it'd take the return value of getConnected, which is null. As for your second solution, PHP does not allow you to overload methods in the traditional programming sense—what PHP calls overloading is not related to having different arguments.

Comment: I'm putting mysqli_connect into MyConn::$active_connection... im not even using MyConn::$conn... PHP doesn't allow overloading... It behaves the same way Java behaves though - you can have multiple constructors with different numbers of parameters... but ive updated my answer to make you happy. id appreciate it if you stopped treating me like i dont know what im talking about

Comment: No, I'm referring to the first solution, which would return null. And no, you cannot redeclare constructors in PHP—I've uploaded your source  (with syntax corrected) to http://www.birid.org/abc.php, but you can try it yourself. Furthermore, I apologize if you're taking me the wrong way—I'm only trying to explain why your solutions were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are slightly wrong about the error message.
I suspect the error you are actually seeing is:

```
Undefined property: myClass::$conn
```

If this is true, its pretty clear.  `$conn` is local only to the `con()` function, and does not exist in the `myF()` function.

You should declare `$conn` as a property of `myClass`.

Answer (score -1):

`$conn` is  only declared within the scope of `public function con()`.  Declare it in `myClass` first and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that the variable is public. You should either Specifically make it public, or create a function, which returns the connection.

Answer (score -1):

You should add a field to "MyClass" which will store the pointer to the connection between methods.

Another useful things:
Do not use "var", it is deprecated in php5 and is equal to "public" just for backward compatibility.
Try not to use public fields in your classes, it is considered as a bad tactic in oop programming (google encapsulation).
As you can guess, if you create another MyClass instance, and you call the "con()" method for this instance, you will have 2 opened connections to your database, which is very bad for performance. The solution is the singleton pattern (google singleton, there are some php examples)

Comment: If I use the singliton pattern w/ temporary tables will that mess up anything? ie will userA's temporary table interfere w/ userB's temporary table?

Comment: With singliton you create a single connection per request, so userA's tepmporary table will not interfere with userB's temporary table because these are temporary tables of different connections. Without singleton pattern you create a connection per instance of your database class and temporary tables will be useless if you want to use them between different classes in a single request.